VS Code debugger says a variable is undefined, but the variable appears in console log
Try running this particular piece of javascript code in VS Code's debugger mode.
(async()=>{
 let t = 1;
 console.log(t);
 for(let i =0 ; i<99999999; i++) {
     continue;
 }
 debugger;  
})();

At the debugger breakpoint, it says that the 't' is undefined

Any idea why this happens?

At a guess - JIT optimised away t because it wasn't referenced during or after the loop. Does this happen in any code where it makes sense to check this? Because if it's just this one example, it seems pretty inconsequential.

Place a breakpoint, or a debugger statement at the beginning of the function.  It's not so much that t get optimised away, it's just at the point you have placed the debugger command the debugger has not even started capturing scope to place in the variables section.

@Keith I just added another console.log right before the debugger command, and now the debugger is able to identify the variable 't'. So I believe it has got something to do with the optimization.

Yeah, not sure you get what I'm saying.   I said "It's not so much that t get optimised away",  I'm not saying it doesn't get optimised away, but because the debugger was not active initially it never got tracked, and that big delay you put allowed it to be optimised away.   If the debugger is running it doesn't get optimised away, because the debugger will now have a reference to it.  IOW: place a breakpoint on the line let t = 1, notice how t is now still active at the end.
